# How can I get a ListView and TextView to scroll as one unit when content is taller than the screen height?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have a main menu screen with a simple ListView that contains "links" to further screens in my app (Browse, Bookmarks, Settings, About, etc.). Underneath the ListView there is a TextView (more accurately, a TextSwitcher that rotates TextViews) that changes every 10 seconds to display a new "tip".
[image]

In portrait mode, this works fine. There are my five list items in the ListView , and my tip label underneath. However, when I switch to landscape mode, the ListView is taller than the screen. The ListView scrolls normally, but I cannot scroll past the end of the ListView to see the TextView underneath.

I have tried every possible combination of Layouts, wrappers, ScrollViews, and layout_height parameters and I simply cannot get it to behave.

Here is the simplest code I can use to get the result pictured above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ListLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/TipLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ListLayout">
        <TextSwitcher android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TipSwitcher">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="7pt"
                android:id="@+id/Tip1TextView" android:text="Tip: Hello, Android!"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tip: This is the second TextView in the TipSwitcher!"
                android:id="@+id/Tip2TextView" android:textSize="7pt"></TextView>
        </TextSwitcher>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Like I've said, I've already tried so many different combinations that I can't list them, and for the most part I was randomly inserting XML in an attempt to get something to work the way I wanted. So I'd greatly appreciate suggestions as to how I would go about doing this the right way.

Thanks.

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention, this may or may not be relevant. My MainMenuActivity is extending ListActivity. According to the docs, "ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen." But, "If you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate()." So I don't think the ListActivity is interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `TextSwitcher` in the `ListView` itself. You can use `addFooterView()` for this.

Comment: Huh, never thought of that. Didn't think it was possible to put Views inside anything other than a Layout. I am now able to see the TextSwitcher in landscape mode, however it is behind the ListView as opposed to underneath it.

Comment: @Anidamo: That should not be possible. If you have not done so already, you need to remove the `ViewSwitcher` from the layout XML file. Either construct it in Java code or inflate it from its own layout XML file, to get the View to provide to `addFooterView()`. Here is a sample project showing the use of `addFooterView()`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/HeaderFooter/

Comment: Yep, that turned out to be the issue. Moved the TextSwitcher over to its own xml file, inflated it using View.inflate, and passed it to addFooterView. Had to call addFooterView *prior* to setAdapter (as per the javadoc) to get it working properly.

Thanks.

Comment: One more small thing: since addFooterView is essentially adding another row to the listview, the Tip field is highlighted in orange when tapping on it. How can I stop that behavior?

Comment: @Anidamo: Using `addFooterView()`, you probably cannot stop that. At the cost of more complexity, you could steal a peek at my `MergeAdapter` and use its techniques to create your own adapter that stitches together your regular adapter and a third adapter that just returns your footer, with the appropriate methods set to "disable" that footer row. I have on my 18,000-item to-do list to add smarts to `MergeAdapter` directly to support this concept. http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: @Anidamo: If, OTOH, you'd be more comfortable just saying the `TextSwitcher` was visible all of the time, anchor it to the bottom of the screeen (`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`) and anchor your `ListView` to the top of the screen (`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`) and top of the `TextSwitcher` (`android:layout_above="@id/TipLayout"`).

Comment: I'll take a look at the MergeAdapter to see if I can create something to do what I need. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured I'd mention that I was able to stop the orange highlight simply by setting the TextSwitcher's clickable property to true. Then, it intercepted tap events before they were caught by the ListView "underneath" it.